# IE only prints properly through Print Preview?

Tags: internet-explorer, printing

Has anyone come across the problem where Internet Explorer won't print a page properly unless I go through print preview? If I just click print directly, or the print button on the page, it prints two pages, the first with just the heading on it, and the second one blank.

If I go through Print Preview, it shows the correct format of the page, and the prints it out correctly too if I print from Print Preview.

The page does have some print specific CSS but I don't see how that would be causing a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem. Adding the following meta data forcing it back down to IE7 standard rendering mode fixed it for me.

```
< meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue that Print Preview shows Letter as a default but when you hit print it uses A4 as default. (A4 is 210x297, letter is larger)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Printed thousands of pages properly in IE7 then upgraded to IE8 and only the first page prints unless I do print preview. Have switched to Mozzilla for my printing jobs. (PS It does print some multi-page websites properly but not the one I printed thousands of pages for using IE7).

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem.  Print Preview is the only workaround I've found.  How do you submit a bug request to Microsoft??

Comment: You want to "request" bugs from microsoft?  I think they provide us enough as it is!